# Get IE after login, url change

Tags: excel, vba

I use Excel VBA login a web, after login the URL change and I can't control that page after login.

After login:

I `Dim` and `Set` another `InternetExplorer` object, try to get the page, and use `.locationURL` but it still show previous URL.

I find some method like shell to get IE and not worked.
But when I use F8 run the code line by line, the `.locationURL` can show the URL after login.

How can I do that let the second print show the URL after login?

```
Dim Login As InternetExplorer
Set Login = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Login.Visible = True
Login.navigate ("This is Login page")
Do While Login.Busy Or Login.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Debug.Print Login.LocationURL ' show URL of login page

Login.document.getElementsByTagName("input")("tbx_No").Value = ID
Login.document.getElementsByTagName("input")("tbx_Pwd").Value = pwd
Login.document.getElementsByTagName("input")("btn_ok").Click
Do While Login.Busy Or Login.document.readyState <> "complete": Loop

Debug.Print Login.LocationURL ' show URL of page after login
```

EDIT:

```
Dim Login As InternetExplorer
Set Login = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Login.Visible = True
Login.navigate ("This is Login page")
Do While Login.Busy Or Login.readyState <> 4: DoEvents:
Debug.Print Login.Busy & " " & Login.readyState
Loop
Debug.Print Login.LocationURL

Login.document.getElementsByTagName("input")("tbx_No").Value = ID
Login.document.getElementsByTagName("input")("tbx_Pwd").Value = pwd
Login.document.getElementsByTagName("input")("btn_ok").Click
Do While Login.Busy Or Login.document.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents:
Debug.Print Login.Busy & " " & Login.document.readyState
Loop
Sleep (5000)
Do Until Login.LocationURL = "This is page after login": DoEvents: Loop
Debug.Print Login.LocationURL
```

Debug print like this:

```
True 1
True 1
True 1
False 4
This is Login page
```

And code still running, I think it stuck in :

```
Do Until Login.LocationURL = "This is page after login": DoEvents: Loop
```

But why it doesn't print the second:

```
Debug.Print Login.Busy & " " & Login.document.readyState
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what happens - what does the second `Debug.Print` output?

Comment: It output the URL of login page, but actually after login, URL will change.

Comment: The URL proably changes after some specific amount of time. That's why it works with F8 (the code is run much slower step-by-step than at once using F5). Try to include a wait command to wait eg 5 seconds (until the URL changes). Or run a `Do` loop `While` the `LocationURL` did not change.

Comment: I add both "wait" and "do until" but it doesn't work